# R: prop.test returns different values based on whether matrix or vectors are passed to it

Tags: r, matrix, vector, hypothesis-test

Why would *r*'s `prop.test` function ([documentation here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/prop.test.html)) return different results based on whether I pass it a `matrix` or vectors?

Here I pass it vectors:

```
> prop.test(x = c(135, 47), n = c(1781, 1443))

    2-sample test for equality of proportions with
    continuity correction

data:  c(135, 47) out of c(1781, 1443)
X-squared = 27.161, df = 1, p-value = 1.872e-07
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.02727260 0.05918556
sample estimates:
    prop 1     prop 2 
0.07580011 0.03257103
```

Here I create a `matrix` and pass it in instead:

```
> table <- matrix(c(135, 47, 1781, 1443), ncol=2)
> prop.test(table)

    2-sample test for equality of proportions with
    continuity correction

data:  table
X-squared = 24.333, df = 1, p-value = 8.105e-07
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.02382527 0.05400606
sample estimates:
    prop 1     prop 2 
0.07045929 0.03154362
```

Why do I get different results? I expect the same results for both scenarios to be returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `x` and `n` are entered as separate vectors, they are treated, respectively, as the number of successes and the total number of trials. But when you enter a matrix, the first column is treated as the number of successes and the second as the number of failures. From the help for `prop.test`:

> ```
> x    a vector of counts of successes, a one-dimensional table with two
>      entries, or a two-dimensional table (or matrix) with 2 columns, giving
>      the counts of successes and failures, respectively.
> ```

So, to get the same result with a matrix, you need to convert the second column of the matrix to the number of failures (assuming that in your example `x` is the number of successes and `n` is the number of trials).

```
x = c(135, 47)
n = c(1781, 1443)

prop.test(x, n)  # x = successes; n = total trials
```

> ```
>   2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction
>
> data:  x out of n
> X-squared = 27.161, df = 1, p-value = 1.872e-07
> alternative hypothesis: two.sided
> 95 percent confidence interval:
>  0.02727260 0.05918556
> sample estimates:
>     prop 1     prop 2 
> 0.07580011 0.03257103
> ```

```
prop.test(cbind(x, n - x)) # x = successes; convert n to number of failures
```

> ```
>   2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction
>
> data:  cbind(x, n - x)
> X-squared = 27.161, df = 1, p-value = 1.872e-07
> alternative hypothesis: two.sided
> 95 percent confidence interval:
>  0.02727260 0.05918556
> sample estimates:
>     prop 1     prop 2 
> 0.07580011 0.03257103
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the clarity on this one. The "number of failures" part instead of "number of trials" was something my brain missed. I was expecting the input to be total number of trials and not (1 - successes).